# How to test if my function is returning an instance of another class in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I am new to jest testing.

I have a switch case like this:

```
 export const findType = async (name) => {
    switch(name){
        case "apple":
            return new AppleClass()
        case "mango":
            return new MangoClass()
        default:
            return new VegetableClass()
    }
}
```

Now, i want to write jest test case to check the above switch case. My test case is like this:

```
it('should return AppleClass', () => {
    expect(() => {
       let res =  findType("apple")
       console.log(res)
    }).toReturn(instanceof(AppleClass))
})
```

Console.log(res) prints:

```
Promise{
     AppleClass {
           //some other stuff
         }
}
```

But I'm getting error as

```
Expression expected.ts(1109)
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

at

```
.toReturn(instanceof(AppleClass))
```

How to test this. Any help would be great.

Comment: btw, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) is an operator (without braces).

Comment: @NinaScholz , toReturn(instanceof AppleClass) also gave error as Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

Comment: that is a different error. i don't know.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to set up the function passed to `it`, in a different manner, because the instanceOf operator requires an object to check, like this:

```
object instanceOf AppleClass
```

You should try something like this:

```
it('should return AppleClass', () => {
let obj = findType("apple");
  let isApple = obj instanceof AppleClass;
  expect(isApple).toBe(true);
});
```

See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-pe65w?file=/index.test.js:390-536).

In the case of the function returning a promise, the test should be modified like this:

```
it('should return AppleClass', async () => {
let obj = await findType("apple");
  let isApple = obj instanceof AppleClass;
  expect(isApple).toBe(true);
});
```

I have edited the code in the link above, for the function to return a Promise, do check it.

Comment: thank, that works, but my code returns a promise from the class. I have edited the question. Please help

Comment: Please provide the class definition also in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would also work:

```js
it('should return AppleClass', async () => {
  let result = await findType("apple");

  expect(result).toBeInstanceOf(AppleClass);
});
```